# Run a javascript function on script load

Tags: javascript, jquery, pageload

I am using jQuery.  I keep all of my function definitions wrapped in the $(document).ready event in application.js.  I have a function from it that I would like to call somewhere in the body of the page I am working on.

I was wondering if there is some alternative to the .ready event that will work on a script load.  Ideally I would like to do something like:  $('application.js').ready( call function );

In the jQuery documentation it only mentions the $(document).ready call but I was wondering if this can be altered or if there is some plain javascript alternative.

Comment: Why $(document).ready doesn't suite you?

Comment: Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way.  In application.js the function was defined in the head wrapped by $(document).ready.  I have an ajax call that only happens one page for the site so I wanted to call that function from within the page body.  

I wrapped the function call in $(document).ready as well.  The function call is getting loaded before the function though. I would like a way to test the script load which will be after the page load.

Answer (score 5):

I think you’re looking for [`$.getScript`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/). This jQuery function loads a JavaScript file from the server using a `GET` HTTP request and executes it. You can specify a callback function, to be executed after the script itself has been executed.

```
$.getScript('foo.js', function() {
 alert('foo.js was loaded, do something cool now');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I am curious about this myself, but instinct would tell me you'd want to wait for the document to finish loading before running any javascript.

Comment: Wrong. You would wait for document to load because then all DOM elements will be loaded, and you're sure that you can safely manipulate them. If you load script after element is defined and added to tree (you have closing tag before script) then you can safely manipulate this element.