# page content is not showing after document ready html load

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to load advertisement after page load for that I am using jquery html() method.
Problem is that `$(document).ready(function(){` is redirecting my page and only showing advertisement not the data.

I want to display advertisement and data both in same page and advertisement should be loaded after the page load.

This is my code link http://jsfiddle.net/2MTHE/1/

for checking purpose i have added in `hello how are you` at `.html()` starting that is also not displaying at page.

Comment: Don't use document.write after the page has loaded it'll destroy your page. http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/2MTHE/3/

Comment: @Musa what does the `!` in front of `function` do?

Comment: @ExplosionPills its just like the `(function(){})();` trick but shorter.

Comment: @Musa Code is working properly but i am not getting where you made change

Comment: @Musa advertisement should load on  <div 'class="adver"></div>'

Answer (score 0):

Musa is right.
Using document.write will over write everything in your page.
Try removing document.write and everything will work like a charm.

Or do the document.write first before loading the content of the html file..

For you to load the html content, you can output the content using `document.write` as well..

```
document.write('<div><a target=\"_top\" href=\"http://www.adbrite.com/mb/commerce/purchase_form.php?opid=2233784&afsid=1\" style=\"font-weight:bold;font-family:Arial;font-size:13px;\">Your Ad Here</a></div>');
```

There is a **solution** in your problem within this forum.
Here's the thread:

[Advert inside a div on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8460505/1999395)

[Advert using two div on load](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2957086/1999395)