# Loading js file into div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a js file and execute with :

```
<div id="result">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/tracking.js"></script>
</div>
```

My main page has 2 divs (2 colums in page) and there are buttons on the left div. When i click to the first button, i would like to execute js file and display on the right. I can easily handle html files by :

```
$("#result").load( "test.html" );
```

But for js files i think i need to use getscript. I gave a shot with :

```
$("#result").load("#result",function(){$.getScript("js/tracking.js"); });
```

Ok, it executes the script but not loading into "result" div. It opens a new page and displays the result.

How should i modify?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8460306/loading-javascript-into-div-dynamically

Answer (score -1):

As far as I can understand, you want to load, execute & display js file.

check this [demo][1]

```
  [1]: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WrYQLX
```

Comment: Correct! I have a js file and a button. When i click to button, i would like to execute another js file in my div. That js file executes some codes and display some results. Your code is ok but works in html section. Could you please divide the page %30-%70 vertically and put a button in the first div. When clicking the button, please execute another js which displays hello world in the second div. Please do them only in js window.

Comment: Please check the updated demo @  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WrYQLX and replace "urlforyourscript" in js window with your script url

Comment: Ok, Thanks Arun but it displays in another page.   $("#trackinginfo").html( '<script type="text/javascript" src="js/tracking.js">' +
 '</script>'
); or
$.getScript("js/tracking.js"); I could not make it display in trackinginfo div dynamically!

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for this and let me inspect?

Comment: lets continue on your pen. I created a js file very simple : document.write("Hello World!");alert('aaaaaa'); Here : https://1fichier.com/?m01luth44c     I put this link to $.getScript("https://1fichier.com/?m01luth44c"); alert function works but i can not see document.write in result div.

Comment: let me look into this.

Comment: Lets try writing directly to result div instead of document write. 
Replace your js file content with this:

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Hello World!";
alert('aaaaaa');

Comment: Ok, here is my real js :https://1fichier.com/?lomifn8djt I can't make it run. This js takes an rss feed, parse and display. It works well when i call with <script> in html but not working with getScript. Arun, can you adopt this to your code pen?